# Contextual closure type error when accessing the class file in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, callback, swift4

I am new to swift programming, i have Implemented Speech to text using Microsoft Azure,when i calling the class file i am getting the error like "**Contextual closure type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void' expects 3 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body** " .can anyone help me to solve this error.

```
    //This is the sample code where i am calling the function in class file
        TTSHttpRequest.submit(withUrl: TTSSynthesizer.ttsServiceUri,
                                          andHeaders: [
                                            "Content-Type": "application/ssml+xml",
                                            "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat": outputFormat.rawValue,
                                            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
                                            "X-Search-AppId": appId,
                                            "X-Search-ClientID": clientId,
                                            "User-Agent": "TTSiOS",
                                            "Accept": "*/*",
                                            "content-length": "\(message.lengthOfBytes(using: encoding))"
                        ],
                                          andBody: message.data(using: encoding)) { (c: TTSHttpRequest.Callback)  in
                                            guard let data = c.data else { return }
                                            callback(data)
                    }
//This is the class file where i am getting the error
class TTSHttpRequest {

   typealias Callback = (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?)

    static func submit(withUrl url: String, andHeaders headers: [String: String]? = nil, andBody body: Data? = nil, _ callback: @escaping (Callback) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        headers?.forEach({ (header: (key: String, value: String)) in
            request.setValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
        })
        if let body = body {
            request.httpBody = body
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (c:Callback) in   //In this line i am getting above mentioned error.
            callback(c)

        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: as the error states you can't use a type alias there because it expect 3 arguments. try changing `Callback` to `Data?, URLResponse?, Error?` and `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { 
            callback($0,$1,$2)

        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Leo Dabus commented, you cannot pass a single argument closure (your closure takes one argument `c` of type `Callback`) as a parameter expecting three-argument closure.

This is the effect of [SE-0110 Distinguish between single-tuple and multiple-argument function types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md).
The status of the proposal currently shows as **Deferred**, but the most functionality of this proposal is already implemented and effective in Swift 4, and only a little part (including [Addressing the SE-0110 usability regression in Swift 4](https://forums.swift.org/t/core-team-addressing-the-se-0110-usability-regression-in-swift-4/6147)) is rewinded and under re-designing.

One possible fix would be something like this:

```
class TTSHttpRequest {

    typealias Callback = (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?)

    static func submit(withUrl url: String, andHeaders headers: [String: String]? = nil, andBody body: Data? = nil, _ callback: @escaping (Callback) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        headers?.forEach({ (header: (key: String, value: String)) in
            request.setValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
        })
        if let body = body {
            request.httpBody = body
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in //<- three arguments
            callback((data, response, error)) //<- Call the callback with one tuple.

        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```